# How to get only second li element using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have three li elements in ul, as shown in the image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zOzD.jpg  I want to retrieve every li element separately specially the second one.

please give me suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
Elements e = doc.select("ul.about-stats>li");
if(e.size() > 2){
   Element firstLi = e.get(0); //to get first 
   Element secondLi = e.get(1); //to get second 
   Element thirdLi = e.get(2); //to get third 
}
```

or you can use

```
e.listIterator();
```

Comment: I dont understand why i got down votes instead they(who down voted)  should have refer me to a link

Comment: I think this was very basic question and most of people not aware of Jsoup library as it not that much popular, which is third party.

Comment: i think no place here for beginners like me

Comment: No, Actually some people think, stackoverflow is last option for help unless you have done research before.